# Parity time sync issue

Tags: parity, parity-wallet, parity-signer

I'm having an issue with time synchronization on Parity. This is the error I get under status and time synchronized, "Unable to reach time API: NTP error: NTP server is not provided.. Make sure that your clock is synchronized."

I'm using Windows 7. I tried syncing my computers time again but it still says that.

When I go to time.is though it says, "Your time is exact!The difference from Time.is was -0.115 seconds (±0.082 seconds)."

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @lungj I looked at that but there is no solution. Syncing your clock on Windows doesn't fix it.

Comment: My answer there is that this message indicates that Parity was unable to check the time on your computer, not that that the time is necessarily off. It sounds like your clock time is fine. Editing my other answer for clarity/emphasis.